# Adding a gesture recognizer to GMSMapView in order to get .begin/.ended/.change gestures

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Getting Pan gesture on GMSMapView object won't return anything. I don't know if this will work. However on the override delegation on didChange function won't do much, because I wanted to get the .began/.changed/.ended state just like on a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Adding a gesture recognizer on GMSMapView object but it won't return any of the gestures state.

//Initializitaion

```
let panGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(recognizer:)))

mapView?.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
mapView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

//function

```
@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    var animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator()

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        print("began")
    case .changed:
        print("changed")
    case .ended:
        print("ended")
    default:
        print("none")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set this to false `mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false`

When this is set to `true` (by default), all the gestures are handled by the GMSMapView.

You can set it to false to handle this by yourself. Because `pan gesture` is handled by default.

Check the documentation : [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a18ee69e2a06e4934beb9103663d6a73f)

May I ask for what purpose you want to handle all the gestures?

Comment: Sorry haven't included that I already tried this. And still pan gestures aren't firing.

Comment: The purpose is to handle pan gesture in order for me to add some animation on the marker.

Comment: I already solved it, I am initialising a UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UIPanGestureRecognizer.  lol

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you